# Can req.body in express grab a value from div tag instead of input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express

I am new to html, Jquery, express, and  Javascript

In express, I have this console.log(req.body.salty), this only works when I have my html in a form that has an input tag with name="salty". I can see the value that I entered in.

Is there a way to do the same thing but with a div instead of a input tag? Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @hidden_4003 could you give me a resource I could read up on. I have been trying to search I can't seem to find a resource.

Comment: So you use expressjs framework and you didn't read the framework's documentation? It is located at http://expressjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely. `request` is built based on the HTTP request sent from the browser based on the HTTP spec.  That spec says that there's a couple types of content you can send from the client to the server, but the upshot is that the only content that will be there by default is what is sent up from form fields. You can use JavaScript to take content from elsewhere on the page and put it in (for example) a hidden form element, or to send a custom crafted HTTP request (e.g. via Ajax).  But in general, if all you're working with is an HTML page and whatever it can natively send up the pipe, that 'something' will be whatever is in named form fields.

Comment: Technically request can also be via websocket which is not HTTP.

Comment: Not in Express, which is what his question was about.